# library management system in django

Tags: python, database, django-models

I just started developing library management system using django. I'm new to Django, so where do you suggest me to start? I used the tutorial on django's website but I think it's not enough for me to do something like this. 
I will probably use this ER diagram of database of the system, but probably I should transfer it into django model, right? 
[image: conceptual er diagram of library]

Anything more you can suggest me it will mean a lot for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I firmly recommend starting with this tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

What you gonna do then is just use more models than they have in tutorial. The idea is - you describe you domain with classes called "models". Each of them describes an entity from your domain. You also describe their relations and that's it. That's the idea.